# SQL query in C# not working as expected

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

hello i am having an issue when using SQL in C#

the problem is that no results are being returned or at least results.Rows.Count is at 0 but when i change the query from

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM local_entry WHERE filename ='" + filename + "' AND size =" + filesize;
```

to `String query = "SELECT * FROM local_entry";`

6 results are counted when there should be 7

I have ran the query in a sql browser and it returns 1 result so the syntax is correct with a known result

Below is the full code i am using for the query

```
public DataTable GetDataTable(string sql)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
            cnn.Open();
            SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
            mycommand.CommandText = sql;
            SQLiteDataReader reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(reader);
            reader.Close();
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
        return dt;
    }

    private bool ExecuteSQLQuery(String filename, String filesize)
    {
        filesize = filesize.Replace(",", String.Empty);

        String query = "SELECT * FROM local_entry WHERE filename ='" + filename + "' AND size =" + filesize;


        var results = GetDataTable(query);

        if (results.Rows.Count > 0)
        {              
            return true;
        }         
        return false;
    }
```

Edit - Intention of the code is simple comparing a list of file names and their sizes agianst a .db log from google drive Local_entry has 5 columns inode_number (int), filename(text) modified(int) checksum(text) and size(int) 
If a file on the list matches an entry in the .db it will save the name of the matching file to .txt

Solved. turns out the .db was acting strange and when i copied from the original with updated entries the updates were not being carried over hence why no results why this occured i have no idea but thank you for all the help and the code is alot cleaner now

Comment: print out your sql and run it in a UI.  I bet you only get 6 results.  The problem is probably something to do w/ the formatting of your variables or sql string. (ie. single quotes, or spaces)

Comment: Also, what sql type is size?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do with `throw new Exception(e.Message);`?

Comment: Most of the code has been assisted by a friend as i am quite new to c# but the issue is baffling him too. also edited adding the structure of the table

Comment: try the query in Like clause and trim the filename. Also use string.Format() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sql.

```
string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM local_entry WHERE filename LIKE '%{0}%' AND size = {1}", filename.trim(), filesize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these two changes --

```
SQLiteCommand mycommand = cnn.CreateCommand();
```

and

```
mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

I would also suggest `using` it makes for nicer code.  Like this:

```
using (SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection))
{
  using(SQLiteCommand mycommand = cnn.CreateCommand())
  {
     mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     mycommand.CommandText = sql;
     using (SQLiteDataReader reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader())
     {
        dt.Load(reader);
     }
  }
  mycommand.Close();
}
```

PS -- you have two other issues in your code you should fix -- a catch that does nothing and vulnerability to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use and Adapter to load the DataTable than the Reader, if memory serves you have to "read" from the adapter, probably why your seeing no results:

```
        public DataTable GetDataTable(string sql)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection))
            {
                using (SQLiteCommand mycommand = cnn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    mycommand.CommandText = sql;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        using (SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter())
                        {
                            da.SelectCommand = mycommand;
                            da.Fill(dt);
                            return dt;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
```